# What is BLE Tags and replationship between BLE Tags, Beacons and iOS custom app

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I have gone through articles but still, I have confusion on BLE Tags.

What are BLE tags? Is it possible to make any relationship between Beacons, BLE Tags and iOS custom app?

Comment: https://medium.com/@steffenbuenau/ibeacon-or-ble-tag-clearing-up-some-terms-28c5b9a1f048 tags are beacons. But tags are "with things" and inherently have information that the "thing" they're attached to would expect to give. Like weather info on a weather station.

Comment: Where did you see the term"BLE tags"? It may be a particular vendor's marketing term